# MEAN.JS module factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, meanjs

Im using MEAN.JS, and I can't figure out exactly what this piece of code does:

File:

```
public/modules/users/services/authentication.client.service.js
```

Code:

```
'use strict';

// Authentication service for user variables
angular.module('users').factory('Authentication', [

    function() {
        var _this = this;

        _this._data = {
            user: window.user
        };

        return _this._data;
    }
]);
```

Why does it make a copy of 'this', add a property and then return that property instead of doing something like:

```
'use strict';

// Authentication service for user variables
angular.module('users').factory('Authentication', [

    function() {

        return {
            user: window.user
        };

    }
]);
```

Comment: if feel both are the same thing , it's just like assigning some value to a variable and returning or straight way return the value. with respect to meanjs i test both are working fine.